# Does resque-scheduler need a resque task in order to run the queued jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque

I'm wondering if resque-scheduler needs a resque instance to run the jobs in a specific queue, or it's mandatory for resque-scheduler to use the `resque:work` task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - the resque:work task starts a worker instance that processes each of the declared queues.  So yes, it's mandatory to have a instance to process the queues, and yes the reque:work task can be used for this - the 2 aren't contradictory.  Perhaps you can clarify your question if this doesn't help you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you definitely need to have a resque worker running to process the jobs, with a command like this:

```
QUEUE=* rake resque:work
```

Resque-scheduler puts the jobs on a queue when it's time for them to be executed, but doesn't execute them itself.  That's why you only run one instance of resque-scheduler, and as many resque workers as you need to keep up with the jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Resque Scheduler is basically a scheduler. It keeps looking for the schedule time and then, when it is time to execute them, it takes the arguments specified in the your resque scheduler.yml, and pushes the job into the queue specified in the scheduler.yml.

Now it up to resque task that is started by:

```
QUEUE=* rake resque:work
```

to pick the job from queue and operate on it.

Consider resque scheduler as a `cron job` whose only task is to push the message in the specified queue. It is up to the resque-worker now to start processing it.